# bower install ngCordova doesn't work any ideas how to fix

Tags: cordova, mobile, ionic-framework

I try to install ngCordova after installed bower but I have an error that 
bower is not recognized as an internal command any ideas how to fix this problem
[image]

Comment: `npm install bower -g`

Comment: Try with `sudo npm install -g bower`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First check bower is installed with your machine using the following Command

```
bower -v
```

It gives any results with version number then try to install 'ngCordova' like

```
bower install ngCordova
```

then need to add ngcordova library before cordova.js

```
<script src="lib/ngCordova/dist/ng-cordova.js"></script>
<script src="cordova.js"></script>
```

If bower is not installed then need to follow these steps:
1) Install bower globally by npm(NodePackageManager)

```
npm install -g bower
```

2) Check the version

```
bower -v
```

3) Now install ngCordova

```
bower install ngCordova
```

4) Need to add ngcordova library before cordova.js

```
<script src="lib/ngCordova/dist/ng-cordova.js"></script>
<script src="cordova.js"></script>
```

That's it. Surely It works :-)